# rotate sprite without stretching

Tags: opengl, c++, glm

I am attempting to rotate the sprites in my game, but they get stretched whenever it happens. I know that it is due to the screen not being square, but I can not figure out the correct way to compensate for that.

[image]
[image]

The left was taken from a non square screen, and the right is from a square screen. I need to scale it in a way that it will be normal again.
The code that I am using to move and rotate the sprites is below:

```
glm::mat4 temp = glm::mat4(1.0f);
float angle = glm::radians(45.0f);
temp = glm::scale(temp, glm::vec3(xScale,yScale, zScale));
temp = glm::rotate(temp, angle, glm::vec3(0f, 0f, 0f));
temp = glm::translate(temp, glm::vec3(coor[0], coor[1], 0.0f));
trans = temp;
```

coor is just the new coordinate to move the sprite to. What is an equation that can get me the X,Y,and Z Scale? I have access to the screen aspect ratio, and I know it has something to do with it. I tried multiplying it by the screen ratio, but that didn't work. I multiplied them by the sin and cos of the angle, but that didn't work either. What is an equation that works?

Comment: What happens if you rotate before scaling?

Comment: @Pikalek The same stretching would happen. I would still need the x,y,and z scale

Comment: I'm not suggest that you drop the scaling, I'm suggesting that you scale after rotating. Matrix multiplication is not commutative, which means the order of operations matters, as [shown here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22076364/950488).